# add to compare doesn't work

Tags: magento2, php, theme, phtml, compare

When I want to add a product to compare list I get the error `"page not found"`.
The wishlist works fine, if I access the link from `"mydomain/catalog/product_compare/add"` it is redirected to `"mydomain/catalog/product_compare/index"` and it says that `there are no product to compare`. It happen only when I add product to compare list.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you use Amasty_ShopbySeo extension and have 'Stores->configuration->Improved Layered Navigation: SEO->SEO URLs->Add Suffix to the Brand Pages and All-products Pages' set to 'Yes'. They don't check routes and add suffix defined in 'Configuration - Catalog - Catalog - Search Engine Optimization - Category URL Suffix' to the end of your request in the seofyUrl() method in vendor/amasty/shopby-seo/Helper/Url.php:

```
if ($this->hasUrlSuffix || $this->getRequest()->getMetaData(Data::SEO_REDIRECT_MISSED_SUFFIX_FLAG)) {
        $identifier = $this->addCategorySuffix($identifier);
    }
```

So, finally you get URL like this 'catalog/product_compare/add/.html', where .html is your suffix and get new weird request.